# using the %in% operator on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a set, `W <- c("a","b","c")`
And a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c("a","b","c"), col3 =c("t","b","p"))
```

I want to run the `%in%` operator on multiple columns to return `TRUE/FALSE` for columns 2 and 3. I want column 1 to remain the same.

I know I can do

```
>df$col1 <- df$col1 %in% W
```

and

```
>df$col2 <- df$col2 %in% W
```

I'm unsure how I can do this in one line. I am also fairly new to R and programming in general.

Comment: `df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], '%in%', W)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could apply a function across both of the columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

W <- c("a","b","c")
df <- tibble(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c("a","b","c"), col3 =c("t","b","p"))

df |>
  mutate(across(c(col2, col3), \(x) x %in% W))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    col1 col2  col3 
#>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 TRUE  FALSE
#> 2     2 TRUE  TRUE 
#> 3     3 TRUE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df[,2:3] <- apply(df[,2:3], 2, function(x) x %in% W)

#  col1 col2  col3
#1    1 TRUE FALSE
#2    2 TRUE  TRUE
#3    3 TRUE FALSE
```

The `2` in `apply` applies the function across columns (`1` would apply across rows). The df[,2:3] identifies only the second and third columns (could also do `df[,-1]`).

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` is designed for such operations on data frames.

`apply` is actually designed for matrices, and works slow on data frames.

The `%in%` operator is actually the function `` `%in%`() `` (try `` help(`%in%`) ``), so we may use it's name in the `lapply` and don't need an anonymous function (those with `function(x) ...`).

```
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], `%in%`, W)
df
#   col1 col2  col3
# 1    1 TRUE FALSE
# 2    2 TRUE  TRUE
# 3    3 TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer from a more efficient coder

Comment: @TarJae I have no clue, I think you'll have to ask someone from the tidyverse folks.

Comment: @TarJae Haha :) Here is some reading for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55437

Comment: Now the same comment as above, but with the knowledge provided by jay.sf. Hurray: I like this. Tried to apply \`%in%\` like \`-\` or \`*\` in across but get `error unexpected symbol`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation of the given solutions:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-col1, ~. %in% W))
```

```
  col1 col2  col3
1    1 TRUE FALSE
2    2 TRUE  TRUE
3    3 TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `as.matrix`

```
> df[-1] <- as.matrix(df[-1]) %in% W

> df
  col1 col2  col3
1    1 TRUE FALSE
2    2 TRUE  TRUE
3    3 TRUE FALSE
```